# Android Firebase 2.4 IllegalStateException using new ref.updateChildren()

Tags: java, android, firebase

When using Firebase 2.4 `ref.updateChildren()` with HashMap, other than `HashMap<String, Object>` (e.g. `HashMap<String, User>`) getting the IllegalStateException.

```
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863): Process:
> com.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 6863 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863): java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Could not execute method of the activity 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4035) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4881) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19592) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4030) 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   ... 11 more 09-29 18:03:21.680:
> E/AndroidRuntime(6863): Caused by:
> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse node with class
> class com.xxx.xxx.xxx.User 09-29
> 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):     at
> com.firebase.client.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:84)
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> com.firebase.client.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:12)
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> com.firebase.client.utilities.Validation.parseAndValidateUpdate(Validation.java:127)
> 09-29 18:03:21.680: E/AndroidRuntime(6863):   at
> com.firebase.client.Firebase.updateChildren(Firebase.java:438)
```

**EDIT**:

Is there a way to pass custom HashMap like `HashMap<String, User>` to `ref.updateChildren()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your last question:

> Is there a way to pass custom HashMap like HashMap to ref.updateChildren() ?

The Firebase SDK for Android/Java doesn't support directly passing POJOs (like your `User` class) into `updateChildren()`.

But what you can do is convert the POJO into a `Map` with:

```
Map<String, Object> userMap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(user, Map.class);
```

Then you can put the map of values into the values that you're passing into `updateChildren()`:

```
updates.put("users/"+uid, userMap);
updates.put("lists/"+uid+"/mine, "value");

ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank! This approach is much more concise than converting User to a map field by field.

Answer (score 5):

As in the code snippet from the [Official Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) to avoid this issue one has to re-write custom structure like this:

```
Map<String, String> newPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
newPost.put("title", "New Post");
newPost.put("content", "Here is my new post!");
```

And then put it instead of custom data model:

```
Map<String, Object> updatedUserData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updatedUserData.put("users/posts/" + newPostKey, true);
updatedUserData.put("posts/" + newPostKey, newPost);
```

Using custom data model instead of `newPost` causes IllegalStateException.