# ClassMapper warnings after upgrading Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After upgrading to Firebase 3, I started recieving the following errors when serializing java.util.date:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for day found on class java.util.Date (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
>
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for timezoneOffset found on class java.util.Date (fields/setters are case sensitive!)

Will they affect anything?

How can I avoid those warnings?

Comment: You cannot serialize a `java.util.Date` object to the Firebase database. I doubt this was possible before either, although I never tested it.

Comment: it is working. Now as well as before. the only problem is that now it issues a warning. What is then your suggestion for serializing dates?

Comment: It's generally thought to be a good idea to use a primitive long or Long object to store the date as a unix timestamp, and convert it to a human-readable formatted date object on the client.

Comment: Sounds like a very prudent design. I was hoping to have a generic cots/Open source solution available for such a standard demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335712/android-firebase-9-0-0-setvalue-to-serialize-enums/37357484#37357484) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357071/converting-to-new-firebase-enums), Firebase doesn't use Jackson anymore and `Date` is not supported. Store it in a Long variable. You can add convenience getters/setters and mark them with `@Exclude` to suppress serialization.