# FireBase Database Exception while uploading values

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Got these errors in Run logcat:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.shikh.regie, PID: 19366
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class com.example.shikh.regie.User
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamm.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamm.zzbt(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.shikh.regie.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)

Dont know whats the problem.why it is not able to parse the node

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText name,email,phone;
private Button btn;
private DatabaseReference mDatabse;
private String name1,email1,phone1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AppUsers");

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    name1 = name.getText().toString();
    email1 = email.getText().toString();
    phone1 = phone.getText().toString();
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
            DatabaseReference ref=mDatabse.child("AppUsers");
            mDatabse.setValue(email1,new User(name1,email1,phone1));
            mDatabse.setValue(users);
        }
    });

}
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.example.shikh.regie;


public class User {
String name,email,phone;

public User(){}

public User(String name, String email, String phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse node with class class CLASS\_NAME android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538330/com-firebase-client-firebaseexception-failed-to-parse-node-with-class-class-cla)

Comment: @PsyGik the question you linked called `updateValues()`, which this question doesn't. So while the error message is the same in both, I doubt it's the same cause.

Comment: No Duplicate class @PsyGik

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work:

```
mDatabse.setValue(email1,new User(name1,email1,phone1));
```

The only [matching overload of setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)) is:

> `public Task<Void> setValue (Object value, Object priority)`
>
> Set the data and priority to the given values.

In this overload the second argument is a priority value, which has to be a primitive object.

It seems more likely that you're looking to do:

```
mDatabse.child("email1").setValue(new User(name1,email1,phone1));
```

This will set the new user as node `email1` under the reference.

Comment: i want the parent node should b named as the user's email...each user will have his own record under his parent node a his email

Comment: For that you'd specify the email address instead of `email1` in the above snippet. Just be sure to encode the email, since `.` is not allowed in Firebase keys. The common way is to replace the `.` by a `,`.

Comment: Note: email addresses can contain many characters which are not allowed in a firebase key. Also using email as key does not allow users to change their email address. To solve both I store users using a UUID. On start of my application, I just load all users in memory in a hash map by email address.

Comment: @bluevoid The set of disallowed characters in Firebase keys is quite small and most of those cannot occur on an email address. The dot `.` is really the only one we encode as far as I know. Loading all users into memory may work when you app starts, but becomes a scalability bottleneck if/when you have thousands/millions of users.

Comment: Ok, it is not really bigset: not allowed in firebase fieldname: .$[]#/ Allowed in email:  !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~; and [] are allowed when between quotes. So to get complete coverage you need to replace all of them. See discusion here: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/154q27rryc/firebase-no-dot-allowed-in-key-name-how-to-create-an-email-index. Their solution is to urlencode the email AND replace the dot. Loading all users will become a bottleneck when more than a few thousand, that is true.

Comment: Actually it is storing the values..but deletes it after 5 or 6 secs.. I've used name instead of email