# Storing data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with storing data in the Firebase Realtime Database. There are no errors but nothing is stored in the database. I have tried with different guides, tutorial (on yt) posts (found here) but none of them worked. Is there a working way that allows me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance everyone and sorry if my English is not perfect.

```
public void registration() {

        if(!validation())
            return;

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating account...");
        progressDialog.show();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reff = mDatabase.getReference();

        user = new User();
        String tableName = "Users";

        Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //register user in firebase
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    user.setUser(mFullName.getText().toString().trim());
                    user.setEmail(mEmail.getText().toString().trim());

                    userMap.put(fullName, email);
                    String currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    reff.child(tableName).child(currentUser).setValue(userMap);
//The following line make app crush

                    reff.setValue(userMap, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                            if (firebaseError != null) {
                                System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User successful created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error! " +
                            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private String user, email, photoUrl, Uid;

    public User() { }

    public User(String uid, String user) {
        Uid = uid;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User(String user, String email, String photoUrl, String uid) {
        this.user = user;
        this.email = email;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        Uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class com.example.xxxxxxxx.activities.RegisterActivity$4$1
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:103)
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:28)
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.PriorityUtilities.parsePriority(PriorityUtilities.java:39)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:199)
        at com.example.xxxxxxxx.activities.RegisterActivity$4.onComplete(RegisterActivity.java:160)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

logcat:

```
2021-01-02 17:07:36.549 20191-20213/com.example.inbioaiqua W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-01-02 17:07:36.557 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.562 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.574 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.580 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.592 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.601 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.611 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.617 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.625 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.631 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.639 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.645 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.657 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.663 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.673 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.680 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.689 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.693 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.706 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.713 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.722 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.729 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.738 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:36.849 20191-20213/com.example.inbioaiqua D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 7LOLWRPcBhVqHm98BVHzpI5FkDG2 ).
2021-01-02 17:07:36.849 20191-20213/com.example.inbioaiqua D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 7LOLWRPcBhVqHm98BVHzpI5FkDG2 ).
2021-01-02 17:07:36.874 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:37.046 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:37.260 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb85360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb831a0)
2021-01-02 17:07:37.260 20191-20214/com.example.inbioaiqua W/OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000001
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM2x33g4syY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy6WexahCdY and others, but nothig works @Alex Mamo

Comment: I've asked what have **you** tried, not what tutorials you watched.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I added the code in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation to see if something is wrong? Besides that, is the onComplete() even triggered?

Comment: I haven't tried adding the listener to setValue (). The onComplete does not generate any errors, in fact in the console there are no traces of errors nor the application crushes.

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia please send your User class and check the firebase realtime database rules.

Comment: I added my User class code and this are the firebase realtime rules: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
} @Suvajit Patra

Comment: Don't insert class objects insert hashmap object.

Comment: make a new hashmap insert the username, email into that and then use `reff.child(tableName).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid()).setValue(userHashmap)`;

Comment: @Suvajit Patra  I've tried also your solution but it doesn't work :(.... i've added this after creating tableName, Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); then in onComplete method i've added: userMap.put(fullName, email);
                    String currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    reff.child(tableName).child(currentUser).setValue(userMap);

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia If you haven't, then you should attach the complete listener. I wasn't asking if the onComple() generates an error, I have asked if it's triggered. Is that Toast message displayed?

Comment: @Alex Mamo yes it's triggered and starts new activity

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia Try to attach the listener and see what you get.

Comment: @Alex Mamo I've tried to attach listener and now i get this:    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class CLASSNAME

Comment: So you found the problem. Please edit your question and add the error message and indicate the exact line at which it occurs. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited my question adding error message and I've indicated the exact line which cause error

Comment: What version of Firebase Realtime Database are you using?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm using version 19.6.0

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia Ok, please try my answer below, and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DatabaseReference` is not initialized, so use the below code on top.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reff = mDatabase.getReference();
```

And add `onComplete` listener to setValue().

```
reff.child(tableName)
.child(currentUser)
.setValue(userMap, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("User data save failure." + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("User data save successful.");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't seem to work. It adds the user only in the authentication section but not in the database

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia use the `onComplete` and in that call startActivity and finish

Comment: and your Map is wrong. `userMap.put("name", fullName);` and `userMap.put("email", email);`

Comment: I edited the code with the changes and added the error above

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia run the program without startActivity and finish and tell me what happens

Comment: and also add listener to `reff.child(tableName).child(currentUser).setValue(userMap)` not only reff.

Answer (score 0):

So in your code:

`reff.child(tableName).setValue(user)`

Here you are trying to set a value for a node that already has branches and Firebase database does not allow that, so what you can do is create another node in the "Users" table to store users. For example:

`reff.child(tableName).child("User1"). setValue(user);`

Here "User1" is just to label the field and can be a simple integer such as "1" too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:
`reff.setValue(userMap, new Firebase.CompletionListener()`

Again, you are trying to set a value of a node with branches which in your case it's the main branch and Firebase database don't allow that. So what you can do is create another node in the reff.

`reff.child(tableName).child(YOUR_DESIRED_CHILD).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()`

Here `YOUR_DESIRED_CHILD` is field name for your `Users` childs.

And it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to the "setValue()" method a CompletionListener object, an option which is not available anymore. To add the user, please use the following lines of code:

```
reff.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "User added successfully!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

And comment or remove the lines that you are using now.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but nothing is added to the database yet.

Comment: Good to hear that the errror is gone. Does this line `Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());` print something in the logcat?

Comment: Yes it prints something. I've edited my post adding logcat

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538330/com-firebase-client-firebaseexception-failed-to-parse-node-with-class-class-cla)** out. Does it solve this issue?

Comment: "didn't solve the issue" doesn't help me, help you. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: I've tried to convert the User class into a Map, but after i've this error:   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Path specified exceeds the maximum depth that can be written (32) or object contains a cycle in path

Comment: That's totally another issue. We usually stick to one question at a time. If you have another problem after the initial one, post a new question for that problem with its own MCVE.

Comment: This new error is due to the change presented in the similar question. I don't think that's the solution, so that link it's not for me

Comment: Is indeed for you, as it yields the same error.

Comment: Yes, but that solution is not complete and didn't work for me

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a service that provides complete solutions. I tried to help you with more than one issue. Note that we usually stick to one question at a time.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the first issue?

Comment: I know and thank you for all the answers and for taking the time spent on this issue. Unfortunately I'm still blocked because nothing is stored in the database yet.

Answer (score 0):

Create Instance of this:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
SetDataFirebaseModel model;
```

in oncreateMethod :-

```
 firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("MessageInfo");
    model = new SetDataFirebaseModel();
```

To add data to firebase:

private void addDatabseToFirebase(String msg) {

```
    model.setMsg(msg);

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            databaseReference.setValue(model);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is fro retrive data:-

```
private void getData() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
            //String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + map);
            tvMsg.setText(map.get("msg").toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```