# Unable to get the image to display in recyclerview from nested realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase realtime database table. I do have an image stored in the Firebase Storage. I'm planning to use multiple of characters in this table under the character column.

[Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch4rJ.png)

I don't understand why I can't get the photo_id from the realtime database. The link (photo_id) is *"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/occreations-b6c14.appspot.com/o?name=characterimage%2FWk80hB04oZRMQxK9Ig0DDgoL5n52%20be58f895-8fda-4dd1-9e15-32e4186eae8a&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UrkBecZTlE4kpNypl-1ACjekw1CIM3UsUxXgRGXHLB4DCmyLDI-i70OxqjwKchf7sf3YURhgCFq3KxV7JUPDy55GyZWSg&upload_protocol=resumable"*
When I click on this link, it says **"Invalid request. X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing."**

But when I tested my code using the link from the URL into the arraylist, it works. But why I can't get the image from my database?

I can't seem to find the problem. I was thinking it could be the arraylist, the photo_id url or the way I upload to the firebase storage/realtime database maybe because I was unable to get the file name as .png or .jpeg and store it as a photo_id?

**UPDATE:** I change the url link to download url from Firebase Storage, but I am unable to retrieve the link from the DatabaseReference, which leaves nothing was adding into the List

I was following this tutorial.[Coding-In-Flow Tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/firebase-storage-upload-and-retrieve-images/part-6-retrieve-images)

**UPDATE2:** I have problems with nested data. I wanted to get ONLY the photo_id value (which is the url) from the realtime database, but I get it as a null value. The placeholder image is a null after I changed the recyclerview. How should I retrieve my data only from the character child to the character_id (which is already unretrievable) unless there is a way to do it. I've been searching through other answers on stackoverflow but none of them matches what I'm looking for.

My log cat says

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -LQq7dIvsJX7GgNfXeIf found on class com.example.linda.originalcharacterapp.model.CharacterInformation
           No setter/field for -LQq7SB5qvcNXdJEzwBh found on class 
           com.example.linda.originalcharacterapp.model.CharacterInformation
           D/TAG: null / null
           W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for username found on class 
           com.example.linda.originalcharacterapp.model.CharacterInformation
           No setter/field for email found on class 
           com.example.linda.originalcharacterapp.model.CharacterInformation
           No setter/field for password found on class 
           com.example.linda.originalcharacterapp.model.CharacterInformation
           D/TAG: null / null
```

[Updated Android Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PfbL.png)

[Android Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk3zu.png)

[Current Image sitting in Firebase Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/649iO.png)

**HomeFragment.class**

```
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (this.getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager (this.getActivity(),2));
    userOCs = new ArrayList<> ();

    //DatabaseReference characterReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

     reference.child(userid).orderByChild("characters").getRef().addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Display images of ocs
            for(DataSnapshot characterSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String photoid = dataSnapshot.child ("photo_id").getValue (String.class);
                    String cName = dataSnapshot.child ("characterName").getValue (String.class);
                    CharacterInformation oc = characterSnapshot.getValue (CharacterInformation.class);
                    Log.d ("TAG", photoid + " / " + cName);
                    userOCs.add (oc);
                    Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "Adding images " + oc.getCharacterName (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
           }
           String file = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/occreations-b6c14.appspot.com/o/characterimage%2FWk80hB04oZRMQxK9Ig0DDgoL5n52%2F3aa5daa6-86b7-41e5-b6aa-2dae58a991ef.png?alt=media&token=5a4e9c2a-e1f8-4d05-904a-a1d934524a09";
           userOCs.add(new CharacterInformation("12", "23",file, " Linda", "12", "Time ANGEL", "Quirk","Justin", "Flight", "lIVES IN MAIN"));

            mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter (userOCs, getActivity()); //where the image is inserted
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
```

**CreateCharacter.class**

```
  private void uploadOC() {
    //String values
    nameValue = cName.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    ageValue = cAge.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    speciesValue = cSpecies.getText ().toString ().trim();
    personalityValue = cPersonality.getText ().toString ().trim();
    familyValue = cFamily.getText ().toString ().trim();
    powerValue = cPowers.getText ().toString ().trim();
    bioValue = cBiography.getText ().toString ().trim();
    currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty (nameValue) && selectedImage != null) {
      //  StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "." + getFileExtension(downloadImage));

        storageReference = storageReference.child("characterimage").child (currentUserID + "/" + UUID.randomUUID ().toString ());

            storageReference.putFile (selectedImage)

                     .addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                           downloadImage = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri ();
                            String characterId = databaseReference.child("characters").push ().getKey(); //creates unique random id
                      //      String photoName = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            CharacterInformation newCharacter =  new CharacterInformation (currentUserID, characterId, downloadImage.toString(),nameValue, ageValue, speciesValue,
                                    personalityValue, familyValue, powerValue, bioValue);

                            Map<String, Object> postValue = newCharacter.toMap();
                            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<> ();
                            databaseReference.child("User Account").child(currentUserID).child("character").child(characterId).setValue(newCharacter);

                            childUpdates.put(nameValue, newCharacter);
                            databaseReference.updateChildren (childUpdates);
                            Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "Failed " + e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener (new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> () {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred () / taskSnapshot
                                    .getTotalByteCount ());
                        }
                    });

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "Character needs name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<CharacterInformation> mDataset;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private Context context;

        private ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
           image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleImage);
        }

    }

    public RecycleViewAdapter(List<CharacterInformation> myDataset, Context context) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.image.setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        CharacterInformation oc = mDataset.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(oc.getPhoto_id ())
                .into(holder.image);
        System.out.println("Binding images...");
        Toast.makeText (context,"Binding images" + oc.getCharacterName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       holder.image.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                DisplayCharacter ocFragment = new DisplayCharacter ();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ocFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are your pictures stored in Firebase Storage? If so, try reading from Firebase Storage. If you saved the pictures with their name being the user's name, you can read from the path with the user's name and receive the picture from there.

Comment: They are stored and I manage to change the photo_id url to the proper one under downlown url from Firebase storage. Now, I'm trying to get the DatabaseReference to make character appear under photo_id. When I run it nothing was happening in the home fragment, but only the testing code. Do I need to get it from the StorageReference?

Comment: Under onBindViewHolder check if oc.getPhoto_id() returns null value of it return your image link

Comment: I think it would be simple to get the images by reading from Firebase Storage. I couldn't get the exact link but I know that a YouTube channel claled Code In Flow has great tutorials on how to retrieve images from Firebase Storgae. You can check them out to learn to read from Firebase Storage. This may help.

Comment: I do have a nested table. When I change it to  characterReference.child(userid).orderByChild(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener ()....I got  W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -LQo0mbXKgYa2HIgkBSn found on class etc.

Comment: And I solve my own problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I already found my answer to this question
This is how I solve my problem, but it's more like I had the no setter field problem and problems calling from the database reference.

[W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742022/w-classmapper-no-setter-field-for-class)

I had to **recall** the database reference to get my nested data.

```
public void retrieveUserOCs() {
        System.out.println("Revoke the character reference ");
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Account");
        DatabaseReference characterReference = reference.child(user.getUid()).child("character");
        // final Query query = characterReference;
        reference.child(user.getUid()).child("character").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ////Loop 1 to go through all the child nodes of characters
                for(DataSnapshot characterSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null ) {
                            CharacterInformation oc = characterSnapshot.getValue (CharacterInformation.class);
                            String ocKey = characterSnapshot.getKey ();
                            System.out.println ("Adding ocs: " + ocKey + " Name: " + oc.getCharacterName ());
                            Log.d ("TAGGING OCS", ocKey + " / " + oc.getCharacterName ());
                            userOCs.add (oc);
                            Toast.makeText (getContext(), "Adding images " + oc.getCharacterName (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        } else { //if user haven't added any characters
                            break;
                        }
                }
                String file2 ="http://ghostfinder101.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/7/3/19737887/published/gear-of-diamond_1.png?1541826567";
                userOCs.add(new CharacterInformation("34", "124",file2, "Diamond", "2002", "Diamond Angel", "Narcissistic","Jahara(friend)", "Flight, shard attacks", "lIVES IN MAIN"));
                mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter (userOCs, getActivity()); //where the image is inserted
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Database error");
            }

        });
    }
```