# Firebase doesn't find fields inherited from super classes

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have the following structure, for example:

```
public class Entity {
   private String name;
   ...
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}

public class Person extends Entity {
   ...
}
```

I have upgraded the Firebase SDK from the old one (before Google buying it) and now I can only obtain the values from the fields declared in that class. Anything that is in a super class can't be accessible.

Every time I use the following code to fetch a `Person` object, it doesn't get the fields declared in `Entity`.

```
dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
```

> ClassMapper: No setter/field for name found on class com.package.Person

*I don't want to write every getter and setter in every inner class, that doesn't make any sense. There's got to be a better (and cleaner) way!*

Comment: use protected instead of priv'ate.

Comment: This is a known issue in the current SDK. See this question for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class

Answer (score 0):

You need to set getter on yout child class.

```
public class Person extends Entity {
    getName(){return this.name;}
}
```

Comment: The thing is, in the real context I have 7 fields inherited from Entity. And 5 classes that extends it. So it will be a mess to create getters/setters for all