# How to use auto-value with firebase 9.2 in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, auto-value

I want to use [auto-value](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) with [firebase 9.2.0+](https://firebase.google.com/). I have the following code:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Office {

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_Office.Builder();
    }

    public abstract double latitud();
    public abstract double longitud();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public static abstract class Builder {

        public abstract Builder latitud(double latitud);
        public abstract Builder longitud(double longitud);

        public abstract Office build();

    }

}
```

But when I make to call this `Office office = childDataSnapshot.getValue(Office.class);` I am getting this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.app.model.Office
```

Somebody have an idea why I am getting this error and how to solve it? I read that firebase is no longer using `jackson` for json serialization. So I am not sure how to specify a kind of `@JsonProperty("latitud")` I have used `@PropertyName` unsuccessfully.

I also tried rename the abstract methods like `public abstract double getLatitud();` and after that the error is the next one:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class com.example.app.model.Office
```

So I am not sure how to solve this.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to **hatboysam** and **Frank van Puffelen** I finally could face this problem with the next solution.

1. I created a [FirebaseUtil enum](https://gist.github.com/epool/131531644952f47072c2f6d8792ddcaa) with two methods for serialize and deserialize objects for Firebase based on **hatboysam** answer and **Frank van Puffelen** comment.
2. I create a couple of `User` and `Phone` classes for testing.
3. Dependencies:

   ```
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.0'
   ```
4. Usage example:

   ```
   User user = FirebaseUtil.deserialize(dataSnapshot, User.class);
   Map<String, Object> map = FirebaseUtil.serialize(user);
   ```

Comment: One question: what is the purpose behind using Auto-Value ? For making Parcelable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible with the default Firebase data mapper, but there is a possible workaround.  First let's explain the errors you're seeing:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.app.model.Office

The Firebase mapper looks for either `public` fields or fields named with the `getFoo`/`setFoo` pattern.  So on your class the mapper does not see any properties.

> java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class com.example.app.model.Office

This is the one I think you'll have trouble getting around.  In order  for the deserialization to work your class needs to have a public, no-argument constructor that the mapper can call via reflection (`newInstance()`).  As far as I know this is not how AutoValue works.

**But don't lose hope!**. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/138) there is a way to make Jackson and AutoValue compatible using the `@JsonCreator` annotation.  So you'll need to use **both Jackson and Firebase** to get the job done here.

Serializing:

```
// Convert to a Map<String,Object> using Jackson and then pass that to Firebase
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.convertValue(office, Map.class);
databaseReference.setValue(map);
```

Deserializing:

```
// Use Firebase to convert to a Map<String,Object>
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,Object>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,Object>>() {};
Map<String,Object> map = dataSnap.getValue(t);

// Use Jackson to convert from a Map to an Office object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Office pojo = mapper.convertValue(map, Office.class);
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that I tried that workaround unsuccessfully, as I could read/research firebase is not using Jackson anymore. So this work around does not worked for me :/

Comment: @epool what exactly about that workaround does not work for you?  While Firebase does not use Jackson internally anymore you can still use Jackson as a companion to firebase.

Comment: To learn how to use Jackson with the latest Firebase SDKs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330

Comment: Never mind, I was trying wrong code. I'll update my question with my **solution**. Thank you very much for you hep guys.!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an `AutoValue` extension for this:

https://github.com/mattlogan/auto-value-firebase

The extension generates a firebase-compatible class, called `FirebaseValue`, as a static inner class in your generated AutoValue class. You can convert between your `AutoValue` class and your `FirebaseValue` class via the generated constructors.

Here's an example, copied from the readme, of what that looks like:

```
@AutoValue @FirebaseValue
public abstract class Taco {

  public static Taco create(String name, List<Ingredient> ingredients, Review review) {
    return new AutoValue_Taco(name, ingredients, review);
  }

  // Create AutoValue_Taco instance from AutoValue_Taco.FirebaseValue instance
  public static Taco create(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    AutoValue_Taco.FirebaseValue taco = dataSnapshot.getValue(AutoValue_Taco.FirebaseValue.class);
    return new AutoValue_Taco(taco);
  }

  // Create AutoValue_Taco.FirebaseValue instance from AutoValue_Taco instance
  public Object toFirebaseValue() {
    return new AutoValue_Taco.FirebaseValue(this);
  }

  public abstract String name();

  public abstract List<Ingredient> ingredients();

  public abstract Review review();
}
```

Comment: Nice! sounds very good! I'll take a look this weekend man, good job! :)

Comment: Does it support Firestore and DocumentSnapshot?

Comment: @Aegir Sorry, no it doesn't. I switched to Kotlin a while ago and haven't used AutoValue since! If you're looking for an open source project though, feel free to open a PR :)