# Storing a list of enums in firebase

Tags: android, serialization, enums, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
public class TestClass {
     public ArrayList<ObjectTypes> list = new ArrayList<>();
     public TestClass(){
        list.add(ObjectTypes.type1);
     }
}

public enum ObjectTypes {
   type1,
   type2,
   type3,
   type4,
}

fb.child("Test").setValue(new TestClass());
```

where fb is a DatabaseReference.

When running the code the application crashes and the following error appears:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to
>   serialize found on class
>   ObjectTypes

This problem did not appear in the old Firebase.

Comment: The Firebase 2.x depended on Jackson for its JSON serialization. We're aiming to get the main use-case natively supported (with a much smaller footprint in your APK size). If you find a need for a use-case that isn't supported (yet), you can still use Jackson. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is currently solved by enumerating the enum elements (enumerating an enum...)

In the above example:

```
public enum ObjectTypes {
   type1(0),
   type2(1),
   type3(2),
   type4(3),
}
```

Hopefully an easier less boiler plated way will be added in the future?