# Firebase timestamps missing from written data in release build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is an Android app with Firebase Android SDK 9.6.1. I'm using data objects for all database read/write operations and many of them contain timestamps. Each of the timestamped data classes contain these attributes:

```
@PropertyName("created_at")
protected Object createdAt = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

@PropertyName("updated_at")
protected Object updatedAt = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

@Exclude
@Nullable
public Long getCreatedAtMillis() {
    return createdAt instanceof Long ? (Long)createdAt : null;
}

@Exclude
@Nullable public Long getUpdatedAtMillis() {
    return createdAt instanceof Long ? (Long)updatedAt : null;
}
```

In debug builds, everything works fine. Sample log of successful write:

```
D/RepoOperation: set: /comments/-KTtr6cXy222oW2kcaGL
D/DataOperation: set: /comments/-KTtr6cXy222oW2kcaGL {
                   comment=Debug test
                   commenter=M6PsqPsESGfcY7CKa9V8Gcdo1qu2
                   context=observations
                   created_at={.sv=timestamp}
                   id=-KTtr6cXy222oW2kcaGL
                   parent=-KTpqfowI4T25gmXCfKY
                   updated_at={.sv=timestamp}
                 }
D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={b={d={id=-KTtr6cXy222oW2kcaGL, context=observations, commenter=M6PsqPsESGfcY7CKa9V8Gcdo1qu2, parent=-KTpqfowI4T25gmXCfKY, created_at={.sv=timestamp}, updated_at={.sv=timestamp}, comment=Debug test}, p=comments/-KTtr6cXy222oW2kcaGL}, r=21, a=p}, t=d}
```

Building the same code in release mode, the timestamp fields are missing from the written data which causes a validation error:

```
10-12 13:13:48.014 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/RepoOperation: set: /comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs
10-12 13:13:48.014 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/DataOperation: set: /comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs {
                                                              comment=Release test
                                                              commenter=M6PsqPsESGfcY7CKa9V8Gcdo1qu2
                                                              context=observations
                                                              id=-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs
                                                              parent=-KTpqfowI4T25gmXCfKY
                                                            }
10-12 13:13:48.014 2974-2974/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast com.lge.softkeypad.intent.HIDE
10-12 13:13:48.014 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/Connection: conn_1 - Sending data: {d={b={d={id=-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs, context=observations, commenter=M6PsqPsESGfcY7CKa9V8Gcdo1qu2, parent=-KTpqfowI4T25gmXCfKY, comment=Release test}, p=comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs}, r=21, a=p}, t=d}
10-12 13:13:48.014 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 35383
10-12 13:13:48.014 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs. Affected: /comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs
...
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5874/org.naturenet D/WebSocket: ws_1 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":21,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Permission denied"}}}
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44947
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/WebSocket: ws_1 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/WebSocket: ws_1 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {d={b={s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}, r=21}, t=d}
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/Connection: conn_1 - received data message: {b={s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}, r=21}
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - p response: {s=permission_denied, d=Permission denied}
10-12 13:13:48.074 5735-5863/org.naturenet W/RepoOperation: setValue at /comments/-KTtsg2SpkVTR9zYWgvs failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Update: After being pointed to the proguard configuration for data objects I added the recommended rules, and then more generous rules to no effect.

Gradle build types:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard true
    proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class org.naturenet.data.model.* { *; }
```

**Update 2: It's not proguard**

```
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
}
```

Same behavior as before.

Comment: Do out have ProGuard configured to retain your model classes [as described in the Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)?

Comment: I had not, but I do now. No change. I also have minify disabled.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with ProGuard.  Looking at other examples, I think you need two asterisks here: `-keep class org.naturenet.data.model.** { *; }`.  For example [see here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/proguard-rules.pro).  Also, should be `-keepclassmembers`.

Comment: @qbix I started with that and expanded the "keep"-ing from other examples until I arrived here. I don't think this really has any effect without minify though.

Comment: Still happening without proguard.

Comment: Is this only happening to you with fields annotated with @PropertyName?

Comment: @hatboysam no change when removing the annotation, nor with 9.8.0

Comment: Sorry let me clarify: are the only fields you see this behavior with the same ones you've marked @PropertyName, or do you see fields missing at random?

Comment: @hatboysam any non-public fields are excluded regardless of PropertyName

Comment: I have reproduced this behavior and am going to log a bug with the Firebase Database team directly, I will let you know what they say.

Comment: Ok this report kicked off a TON of interesting discussion around the office.  The expected behavior is for protected fields to always be treated as private, not public.

When we dove into it we found that this behavior is not respected when using Android Studio with Instant Run.  Are you using Studio?  If so, can you see if the problem persists without Instant Run?

Comment: I'll check with and without tomorrow at the office, but this first turned up in a deployed apk, not a dev environment. Does that mean non-public fields are not supported by the new serializer?

Comment: @hatboysam sorry I forgot to follow up on this! I've tried with and without Instant Run with no difference. I'm not sure how that applies though since I was originally seeing it in a manually installed signed apk.

Comment: @hatboysam any news on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many incremental changes I found that **Firebase serializes class members differently in debug vs release builds**. In release, only `public` members are serialized. Changing the visibility of my timestamp fields fixed the issue:

```
@PropertyName("created_at")
public Object createdAt = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

@PropertyName("updated_at")
public Object updatedAt = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
...
```

Correct output:

```
10-12 15:53:57.155 30970-31048/org.naturenet D/RepoOperation: set: /comments/-KTuSLOHLNQXZooBgBdz
10-12 15:53:57.155 30970-31048/org.naturenet D/DataOperation: set: /comments/-KTuSLOHLNQXZooBgBdz {
                                                                comment=Release test
                                                                commenter=M6PsqPsESGfcY7CKa9V8Gcdo1qu2
                                                                context=observations
                                                                created_at={.sv=timestamp}
                                                                id=-KTuSLOHLNQXZooBgBdz
                                                                parent=-KTpqfowI4T25gmXCfKY
                                                                updated_at={.sv=timestamp}
                                                              }
```

Comment: Surprising.  I hope a Firebaser comments on this behavior.

Comment: Thanks I was facing the same issue