# How to use Jackson annotations in new Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, jackson, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to migrate from Firebase 2.X to the latest version. Is there a way to continue using Jackson annotations? This will reduce the lift of my migration tremendously.

Example:

```
public final class Example {
    @JsonProperty("field_example")
    private int myField;

    Example() {

    }
}
```

gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "In the meantime you can use Jackson (which the Firebase 2.x SDKs used under the hood) to make the inheritance model work." I have the Jackson annotations set up but they do not appear to be working. Firebase complains about missing setters and getters

Comment: Without seeing the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be hard to say anything more than in my answer in the link.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added an example, thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to rename the key where a particular JavaBean field gets stored, use the annotation @[PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName)("new_name") to override the standard JavaBean naming conventions.  You can use this on either a member field (if public with no accessors) or the public accessor methods that get/set it.