# Firebase serialization names

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an object to send some data to firebase. As an example, I use firebase user example:

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I want to encode property names that are sent to firebase. Currently keys are sent using variable names. I want to encode keys something like `Useraname` and `Email`, like `Gson` is doing. I don't want to change variable names.

```
@SerializateName("Username")
public String username;
@SerializateName("Username")
public String email;
```

I used `@SerializateName()`, but is not working. Same with `@PropertyName` that is used by Firebse, is not working. What I can use in order to serializare custom keys?

**Update 1**

```
public class Pojo {
    @PropertyName("Guid")
    public String guid;

   @PropertyName("Name")
   public String name;

   public String getPojoGuid() {
       return guid;
   }

   public void setPojoGuid(String guid) {
       this.guid = guid;
   }
}
```

As you can see in the image, it saves keys based on variable names. I changed property name from annotation for one field and when i save it, it ignores it, but when i change variable name, it save as new entry with key for that new varialbe name.

[image]

In [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) documentation is a method `toMap()`. If i do like that, is working (is not convenient for me), but is not working with `@PropertyName`.

**Update 2**

If i mark getters and setters with `@Exclude` and class with `@IgnoreExtraProperties` is working. I don't have to use `toMap()` method example from documetation. Is using specified name from `@PropertyName`. Not a good thing in my opinion, create confuses.

Comment: @PropertyName works for me with version 11.0.2 of the SDK.  What version are you using?

Comment: Please share the minimum code that reproduces the problem when you serialize/deserializing a POJO with `PropertyName` annotations.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i updated my question with. Is enough?

Comment: Can you help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438092/in-app-billing-connect-to-firebase-and-get-products) please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Firebase SDK uses the annotation it finds for the property whenever it gets or sets its value. That means you need to consider how Firebase gets/sets the value, and annotate each place it looks.

Since you're declaring a `getter` method, Firebase will use that to get the value of the property. It will use the field for setting the value. So the annotation needs to be on both:

```
public class Pojo {
   @PropertyName("Guid")
   public String guid;

   @PropertyName("Name")
   public String name;

   @PropertyName("Guid")
   public String getPojoGuid() {
       return guid;
   }

   @PropertyName("Guid")
   public void setPojoGuid(String guid) {
       this.guid = guid;
   }
}
```

If you'd have getters and setters, the annotation would need to be on those, but not on the fields anymore:

```
public class Pojo {
   private String guid;
   private String name;

   @PropertyName("Guid")
   public String getPojoGuid() {
       return guid;
   }

   @PropertyName("Guid")
   public void setPojoGuid(String value) {
       guid = value;
   }

   @PropertyName("Name")
   public void setPojoGuid(String guid) {
       this.guid = guid;
   }

   @PropertyName("Name")
   public void setPojoGuid(String value) {
       name = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: In this case i can use private fields?

Comment: Yup. Good point. I updated the code fragment in my answer. Note that you can also just use public fields without getters. I now frequently do this in answer, simply because it's less code to share.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the feature of SDK Version 9.2 in which you can now use a new `@PropertyName` attribute to specify the name to use when serializing a field from a Java model class to the database. This replaces the `@JsonProperty` attribute.

```
@PropertyName("Username")
public String username;
@PropertyName("Email")
public String email;
```

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547399/how-to-deserialise-a-subclass-in-firebase-using-getvaluesubclass-class/37548330#37548330) in which Frank van Puffelen explains very clearly this concept.

Comment: I use the latest version. I specified in my question that I tried using `@PropertyName`.

Answer (score 2):

@PropertyName :

> Marks a field to be renamed when serialized. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName)

you have to use `@PropertyName` with public fields and no need for getters/setters

Comment: Is not working. It update keys with same variable name, like `username`, not `@PropertyName("Username")`

Comment: Can you help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438092/in-app-billing-connect-to-firebase-and-get-products) please?

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin Data Class**

Actually you can annotate the getters and setters of the normal class in java/kotlin but the problem is with **data class** as there also we have to annotate the members and simple `@PropertyName("your-serialized-name")` doesn't work as expected.

So lets say you have a data class like this:

```
data class User(
    val name: String,
    val email: String
) {
    constructor(): this("", "")
}
```

Now there are two problems:

**Problem 1.** we cannot annotate the constructor parameterized memeber of data class. Then how we will use annotation ?
**Solution:** we have to annotate in different way using `@get:PropertyName("your-serialized-name)` and `@set:PropertyName("your-serialized-name)`

**Problem 2.** Now you can see that if you use the setter annotation then you have to make the member of the data class as `var` instead of `val` but is this is not what you want as you might want the member as `non-mutable`.
**Solution:** I don't have clear idea as this is bug or something else but if we use simple annotation `@PropertyName("your-serialized-name")` with getter one `@PropertyName("your-serialized-name")` then both the getter and setter annotation functionality can be achieved.

So in the end your data class should look like this:

```
data class User(
    @PropertryName("Name")
    @get:PropertryName("Name")
    val name: String,

    @PropertryName("Email")
    @get:PropertryName("Email")
    val email: String
) {
    constructor(): this("", "")
}
```