# Firebase: Setvalue working with map object but not with POJO

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have no Idea, why Setvalue() works with map object(static data) and throws permission denied as exception when using plain java object with dynamic data(POJO).

**Works**:
Saving data using Map object

```
Map newUserData = new HashMap();
            newUserData.put("Name", getUserName());
            newUserData.put("Surname",getUserName()+"_testSurname");
            newUserData.put("Gender","Gender_data");
            newUserData.put("PhotoURL","");
```

**adding metadata failed com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied**:

Saving data using POJO

```
public class MetaInfo {

private String Name, Surname,Gender,PhotoURL;

public MetaInfo() {}

public MetaInfo(String name, String surname, String gender, String photoURL) {
    Name = name;
    Surname = surname;
    Gender = gender;
    PhotoURL= photoURL;
}

public String getPhotoURL() {
    return PhotoURL;
}
...
...
..
```

Adding data using MetaInfo object:

```
MetaInfo mData= new MetaInfo(name.getText().toString(),
                surname.getText().toString(),
                gender.getText().toString(),
                "");
```

Calling setvalue() with map object works however, permission deined with when  MetaInfo object with valid data is used.

```
DatabaseReference.child(getUid()).child("metadata").setValue(mData).addOn CompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"metadata added ");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"adding metadata failed "+e.toString());
                }
            });
                @Override
```

FB-rules

```
 rules": {
  "test":{
    "$UID":{
      // METADATA
      "metadata":{
        ".read":true,
        ".write":"auth.uid === $UID",
        ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['Name','Surname'])",
        "Name":{
        ".validate":"newData.val()!== null"
        },
        "Surname":{

        ".validate":"newData.val()!== null"
        },
        "$other":{
        ".validate": true
        }
      }
```

Comment: Check ur firebase rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped a few crucial pieces of your `MetaInfo` class. But I'll assume you have these getters:

```
public String getName() { return Name; }
public String getSurname() { return Surname; }
```

These getters map to (follow age-old JavaBean conventions) properties named `name` and `surname`. But your rules validate that any new data has `Name` and `Surname`. It might be hard to spot at first, but the casing is different.

The solution is to annotate the properties with how you want them stored:

```
@PropertyName("Name")
public String getName() { return Name; }
@PropertyName("Surname")
public String getSurname() { return Surname; }
```

If you have corresponding setters for the properties, you'll also need to annotate those.

The easiest way to troubleshoot these problems by the way is to initially write to a location in your database where everything is allowed. That way you can see what the Firebase SDK writes your POJO as, which makes it a lot easier to spot what validation rules it violates.

Also see:

- [Firebase serialization names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306168/firebase-serialization-names/45330351#45330351)

Comment: I do have getter and setter, after applying your suggetion to annotate properties, it get runtime erro `Found setter with invalid case-sensitive name: setName` while reading data, havent test writing yet.

Comment: Please update your question with the minimum code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem is with your `google-services.json` file.

Make sure your `application name` and `client id` are same as in [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

If you are not sure, please re-download `google-services.json` file from your project's console and add it your project.

An also don't forget to set the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Please keep this rules only for testing purposes. Don't keep this rules always like this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In that case neither approach (with a Map or a POJO) would work