# Firebase Java SDK serialized POJO not using gson annotation

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Java SDK underlying use gson to serialize / deserialize pojo. In my class I set the annotation @SerializedName for the serialized json field name. However, after the data was saved to firebase database, the field name is not the value in my SerializedName annotation.

How can I set a customized serializer for forebase java sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the @PropertyName("") annotation

Comment: Check this thread for better usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306168/firebase-serialization-names